# Sidebar: Delayed Hover Activation on Menu Click, Have To Click Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When clicking on a menu item in the sidebar, the hover activation on the menu does not immediately change. Normally, when a menu item is clicked, the active hover state should immediately change to indicate the selected menu item. However, in this case, there is a delay in the activation of the hover state. Users have to click on the menu item again for the hover state to properly update. This creates a suboptimal user experience and disrupts the expected responsive navigation functionality.

This bug affects the user interface in the sidebar section, specifically regarding the active hover state on menu items. The behavior is inconsistent with user expectations and can lead to confusion or navigation errors.

my Sidebar.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  ProSidebar,
  Menu,
  SubMenu,
  MenuItem,
  SidebarFooter,
  SidebarContent,
  SidebarHeader,
} from "react-pro-sidebar";
import { Box, IconButton, Button, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";
import MenuRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuRounded";
import HomeRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeRounded";
import InventoryRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/InventoryRounded";
import HowToRegRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HowToRegRounded";
import logoSMK from "../../assets/images/smk-informatika.png";
import BasicDialogs from "../../components/common/Modal/dialog";
import DaftarUlangForm from "../modal/DaftarUlangForm";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Copyright(props) {
  return (
    <Typography
      variant="body2"
      color="text.secondary"
      align="center"
      {...props}
    >
      {"Copyright © "}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
        Tentackle
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const Item = ({ title, to, icon, selected, setSelected }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  return (
    <MenuItem
      active={selected === title}
      style={{
        color: colors.grey[200],
      }}
      onClick={() => setSelected(title)}
      icon={icon}
    >
      <Typography fontWeight="medium">{title}</Typography>
      <Link to={to} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Beranda");
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const { control, watch, setValue, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
  };
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        position: "sticky",
        height: "100vh",
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        "& .pro-sidebar-inner": {
          background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
        },
        "& .pro-icon-wrapper": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item": {
          padding: "5px 35px 5px 20px !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item:hover": {
          color: "#4389a9 !important",
        },
        "& .pro-menu-item.active": {
          color: "#4389a9 !important",
        },
      }}
    >
      <ProSidebar breakPoint="md" collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <SidebarHeader>
          <Menu iconShape="square">
            {/* LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
            <MenuItem
              onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
              icon={isCollapsed ? <MenuRoundedIcon /> : undefined}
              style={{
                margin: "10px 0 0 0",
                color: colors.grey[100],
              }}
            >
              {!isCollapsed && (
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  justifyContent="space-between"
                  alignItems="center"
                  ml="20px"
                >
                  <Box
                    display="flex"
                    justifyContent="center"
                    alignItems="center"
                  >
                    <img
                      alt="profile-user"
                      width="30px"
                      height="30px"
                      src={logoSMK}
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                    />
                  </Box>
                  <Typography
                    variant="h4"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                    color={colors.blueAccent[400]}
                  >
                    Admin PPDB
                  </Typography>
                  <IconButton onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
                    <MenuRoundedIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Box>
              )}
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </SidebarHeader>
        <SidebarContent>
          <Menu iconShape="square" popperArrow="true">
            <Box paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "10%"}>
              <Item
                title="Beranda"
                to="/beranda"
                fontWeight="bold"
                icon={<HomeRoundedIcon />}
                selected={selected}
                setSelected={setSelected}
              />
              <Item
                title="Siswa Terdaftar"
                to="/siswa_terdaftar"
                fontWeight="bold"
                icon={<InventoryRoundedIcon />}
                selected={selected}
                setSelected={setSelected}
              />
            </Box>
          </Menu>
        </SidebarContent>
        <SidebarFooter>
          <Box
            sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 2, ml: 1 }}
            paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "16%"}
          >
            <BasicDialogs
              title="Formulir Daftar Ulang"
              setOpen={setOpen}
              open={open}
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
            >
              <DaftarUlangForm {...{ control, watch, setValue }} />
            </BasicDialogs>
            <Button
              onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
              sx={{
                backgroundColor: colors.blueAccent[700],
                color: colors.grey[100],
                fontSize: "14px",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                padding: "10px 20px",
              }}
            >
              <HowToRegRoundedIcon sx={{ mr: "3px" }} />
              {!isCollapsed && "Daftar Ulang!"}
            </Button>
          </Box>
          <Copyright sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 2 }} />
        </SidebarFooter>
      </ProSidebar>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from './theme';
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Beranda from "./scenes/beranda";
import SiswaTerdaftar from "./scenes/siswaTerdaftar";
import RequireAuth from './utils/RequireAuth';
import ToLogin from './utils/ToLogin';
import LoginForm from './scenes/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import Initial from './utils/Initial';
import CustomizedSnackbar from './components/common/CustomizedSnackbar';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getMe } from './features/authSlice';

function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      dispatch(getMe());
    }
  }, [dispatch, user]);

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <CustomizedSnackbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Outlet />}>
            {/* Public */}
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />
            {/* Protected Routes */}
            <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
              {/* <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} /> */}
              <Route path="/" element={<Initial />} />
              <Route path='/beranda' element={<Beranda />} />
              <Route path='/siswa_terdaftar' element={<SiswaTerdaftar />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='*' element={<ToLogin />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>

  )

}

export default App;
```

the Video : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/18098285?key=857cceceec0a425d4089e4cf43c180c7
source code : https://github.com/syafiqurohman/try.git

Please help me to solve the bug, thanks in advance